# ERROR TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ɵɵelementStart(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, abp

Error on running angular 13 project. The Project builds fine but is not running on the browser. It gives the following console error:
[image: Colsole Error]

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "onlineorders",
  "version": "8.7.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "publish": "gulp build && ng build --configuration production",
    "start": "gulp buildDev && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200",
    "hmr": "gulp buildDev && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --hmr",
    "test": "gulp buildDev && ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "ng-high-memory": "gulp buildDev  && node --max_old_space_size=2048 ng serve",
    "e2e": "gulp buildDev && protractor",
    "create-dynamic-bundles": "gulp buildDev",
    "nswag": "cd nswag/ && refresh.bat"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.10.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "5.0.11",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^8.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^18.0.1",
    "abp-ng2-module": "^6.4.0",
    "abp-web-resources": "^5.4.0",
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.18",
    "angular-gridster2": "^12.1.1",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^12.1.0",
    "angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.5.1",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.18.3",
    "cron-editor": "2.1.8",
    "dwt": "17.1.12",
    "famfamfam-flags": "^1.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "just-compare": "^1.4.0",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "msal": "^1.4.14",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ngx-barcode": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-captcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^5.0.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "^12.0.0",
    "object-path": "^0.11.8",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "12.0.2",
    "push.js": "^1.0.12",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rtl-detect": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.9",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.1.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^3.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/dwt": "16.1.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.176",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-less": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.5",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "nswag": "13.13.2",
    "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.3.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "abp-zero-template": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/metronic",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "abp.signalr-client.js",
                "input": "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs",
                "output": "/assets/abp"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/famfamfam-flags/dist/sprite/famfamfam-flags.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/file-upload/css/primeng.file-upload.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/autocomplete/css/primeng.autocomplete.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/tree/css/primeng.tree.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/context-menu/css/primeng.context-menu.css",
              "src/assets/fonts/fonts-poppins.css",
              "src/assets/fonts/fonts-roboto.css",
              "src/assets/ngx-bootstrap/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/assets/metronic/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.css",
              "src/app/shared/core.less",
              "src/app/shared/layout/layout.less",
              "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js",
              "node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js",
              "node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js",
              "node_modules/push.js/bin/push.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.js",
              "node_modules/dwt/dist/dynamsoft.webtwain.min.js",
              "src/assets/abp-web-resources/abp.js",
              "src/assets/abp-web-resources/abp.sweet-alert.js",
              "src/assets/abp-web-resources/abp.notify.js",
              "src/assets/canvas-toBlob/canvas-toBlob.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.moment.js",
              "src/assets/metronic/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.js",
              "src/assets/metronic/common/js/scripts.bundle.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash",
              "rxjs-compat",
              "raf",
              "@babel/runtime-corejs3",
              "core-js/modules/es.promise.js",
              "core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js",
              "chart.js",
              "angular2-text-mask",
              "ngx-barcode",
              "rxjs/internal/operators/shareReplay",
              "moment-timezone",
              "moment/min/locales.min",
              "rtl-detect"
           ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": true,
            "aot": true,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "hmr": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "aot": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "abp-zero-template:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "hmr": {
              "browserTarget": "abp-zero-template:build:hmr"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "abp-zero-template:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "abp-zero-template:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/famfamfam-flags/dist/sprite/famfamfam-flags.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/file-upload/css/primeng.file-upload.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/autocomplete/css/primeng.autocomplete.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/tree/css/primeng.tree.css",
              "src/assets/primeng/context-menu/css/primeng.context-menu.css",
              "src/assets/fonts/fonts-poppins.css",
              "src/assets/fonts/fonts-roboto.css",
              "src/assets/ngx-bootstrap/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/assets/metronic/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.css",
              "src/app/shared/core.less",
              "src/app/shared/layout/layout.less",
              "node_modules/@ng-select/themes/default.theme.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/@microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.min.js",
              "node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js",
              "node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js",
              "node_modules/moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js",
              "node_modules/push.js/bin/push.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
              "node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js",
              "node_modules/cookieconsent/build/cookieconsent.min.js",
              "src/assets/abp-web-resources/abp.js",
              "src/assets/abp-web-resources/abp.sweet-alert.js",
              "src/assets/abp-web-resources/abp.notify.js",
              "src/assets/canvas-toBlob/canvas-toBlob.js",
              "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs/abp.moment.js",
              "src/assets/metronic/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.js",
              "src/assets/metronic/common/js/scripts.bundle.js"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "abp.signalr-client.js",
                "input": "node_modules/abp-web-resources/Abp/Framework/scripts/libs",
                "output": "/assets/abp"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "abp-zero-template-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "abp-zero-template:serve",
            "port": 4200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "abp-zero-template",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["./app/*"],
      "@account/*": ["./account/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["./shared/*"],
      "@node_modules/*": ["../node_modules/*"],
      "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"],
      "@metronic/*": ["./assets/metronic/*"]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "strictInputTypes": false,
    "strictAttributeTypes": true,
    "strictOutputEventTypes": false,
    "strictDomEventTypes": true,
    "strictLiteralTypes": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `angular-devkit/build-angular` version is `13.1.2` while your `angular` version is `13.1.1` You may be getting an error because of this difference. Can you sync the versions and try?

Comment: Sorry it did not work. Still giving the same error.